# Recursive SQL query from a BOM table

Tags: sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

I am trying to extract all the components used in the manufacture of an item starting from the top level and trying to develop a recursive query.   Having searched, I cannot find anything similar.
The key fields are:

- Item   This is Part # of the item being built
- Component   This is Part # of the Component being used
- Type   This defines the component type.
         Purchased = 0 or Sub Assembly = 2

If the Component is a sub-assembly, I want the sub-assembly components added to the list (but not the sub-assembly Part #).   If any of these components is itself a sub-assembly, repeat, etc.   I have the top level list but cannot work out how to work the recursion - all examples I can find have multiple levels unlike my 2 and the the need to loop.   This is my code so far.   I am a relative novice in SQL.

```
WITH FullBom (item, comp, type) AS
(
SELECT item, comp, ref
FROM dbBOM
WHERE item = 'A Constant' AND type = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT d.item, d.comp, d.ref
FROM dbBOM d, FullBom FB
WHERE d.comp = FB.item
)
SELECT * FROM FullBom
```

Sample Data

```
Item    Comp't  Type
Part1   Part2   0
Part1   Part3   0
Part1   Part4   2
Part1   Part10  2
Part1   Part11  2
Part1   …
Part4   Part5   0
Part4   Part2   0
Part4   Part6   2
Part4   Part22  2
Part4   Part23  2
Part4   …
Part6   Part7   0
Part6   Part8   0   
Part6   …
```

Output from this data

```
Comp't  Location
Part2   Part1
Part3   Part1
Part5   Part4
Part2   Part4
Part7   Part6
Part8   Part6
...
Partxx  Part10
...
Partxx  Part11
...
```

I have restructured my query in a quasi-code format to try & show the re-entrant structure.   I hope that this may helpto show what I am trying to achieve.   I am trying to regenerate the management reports etc that we had from our previous database.

```
Define Value as text array
Define Int as integer
Order by Item + Type ascending
                                        --Set start values
Value[1] = ‘SearchValue’
Int = 1
Find first record key ‘Value[1] + 0’
Gosub FindLoop
End

FindLoop:
While Item = Value[Int] 
    If Type = 0 then 
        Output data string
    Else Type = 2
        Int = Int + 1
        Value[Int] = Component       --Set Component as search value
        Gosub FindLoop               --Reentrant use of loop
        Int = Int – 1                --Restores previous search value
    End If
    Find Next key ‘Value + Type’
Next
Return
```

Many thanks for your input.   I hope that my alyout is better

Since I do not know how many sub-assemblies I will find in any assembly, and how many sub-assemblies within sub-assemblies, the recursive query seemed the best approach.   I could use Select but only if there was a fixed limit for sub-assemblies at any level.   Since there is no limit, as soon as the code sees a Type=2, it needs to start digging until it comes to the end, then loop back, etc.

Comment: Can you provide some data as test case?

Comment: For starters you should stop using the old style join syntax. It has been replaced by a clearer join syntax over 25 years ago. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Adding some sample data and tables to work with would make this a lot easier. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start for that.

Comment: I will have to build up a sample data as in practice I am having to work with 5 data tables which adds to the complexity.

Comment: @serpiton

Have added some data & an output

Comment: @Sean Lange
 Have added some data & an output

Comment: @serpiton
There is no specified limit.   If I set one, it is certain that it would be exceeded by some user.

Comment: You so greatly oversimplified your sample data is nothing more than a select statement to get it in the format you want. I suspect that is not what you had in mind. Posting this as consumable ddl and dml would go a long way to getting some help. We can't write queries against data until it is in a table.

Comment: Here is a great article explaining how you should post this kind of stuff. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Sean Lange   Added explanation

Comment: @Serpiton   Added explanation

Comment: I think you are missing the point. You need to provide us some data that at least remotely resembles your issue. Preferably in a format that doesn't mean we have to turn it into select statements. I have some level of guessing this is a recursive cte but from your sample data there is no recursion needed, just a simple select statement.

Comment: @Sean Lang    
Thanks for the input.   Hope that this clarifies.

Comment: No it doesn't. There are still two problems here. First is I don't really want to turn that into something I can write a query against for you. The second is there is clarity in what you are trying to do based on your sample data.

Comment: Sean 
   Sorry but you have confused me.   I am very much a newcomer to SQL though I have been writing code on & off for most of my life.   The full  original query is posted on [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/901582-recursive-sql-query.html#post4340446).   I simplified it to get across the principle of what I was trying to do.  I have no wish for someone to write the code for me;  just to guide me on how to get this recursive query working - namely when Type=2.   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are making the join in the opposite way of what you should've.

The first part of a recursive CTE is the anchor, the base of the recursion, the second part the recursion.

For the anchor, as we have no additional field to understand if an item can be a final product or only a componente we take everything, if you the information filter for the final product. The condition on the item should be outside the CTE.

```
SELECT item, SubItem, [type], item AS FinalItem
FROM   dbBOM
```

`FinalItem` will always be the name of the completed item and is added to be used as a filter in the main query.

The recursive part of the query will be

```
SELECT d.item, d.SubItem, d.[type], FB.FinalItem
FROM   FullBom FB
       Inner Join dbBOM d ON d.Item = FB.Subitem AND FB.[type] = 2
```

For every row that is already there, that should be assembled (`[type] = 2`) get the items that corresponds to the subitems in `FullBOM` add them to `FullBOM` and repeat for the new items.

`FinalItem` will stay the same in every level of recursion because we read it from `FullBOM`.

From this take the `FinalItem` you need, take only the items that don't need a sub-assembly (`[type] = 0`) and you'll get

```
WITH FullBom (item, SubItem, [type], FinalItem) AS
(     
  SELECT item, SubItem, [type], item AS FinalItem
  FROM   dbBOM 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.item, d.SubItem, d.[type], FB.FinalItem
  FROM   FullBom FB
         Inner Join dbBOM d ON d.Item = FB.Subitem AND FB.[type] = 2
)
SELECT subItem, Item
FROM   FullBom
WHERE  FinalItem= 'Part1'
  AND  [type] = 0
```

Comment: Serpiton
Thank you very much.   It is clear that I got fully confused.   I'll try it when I back on Wednesday.

Comment: Have amended your code to what II thought it should be.   Am I right ?   Getting Maximum Recursion Limit 100 has been exhausted.
Also, in practice dbBOM is in fact several tables.   Would I be better generating a View with all the data I need ?
Thank you

Comment: I now have it fully working.   Used a View as it seemed to simplify the code & realised I could reuse it.   Thank you very much.

Comment: I have.  Fully working, populated within the company.   Thanks again